# Drop rows using two conditionals - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a df below with numerous duplicate values. Using below, I'm aiming to drop rows where `Value` is unique compared to the previous rows and `Group` is equal to `C`.

Further, where this occurs I want to remove all previous duplicate rows.

```
d = {'Item': ["Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green"],
     'Value': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
     'Group': ["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "B", "B", "D", "D"],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

mask = (df['Item'].isin(['Green'])) & (df.Value.eq(df.Value.shift(-1)))

df = df[~mask]
```

The input is:

```
     Item  Value Group
0     Red      1     A
1     Red      1     B
2     Red      1     B
3   Green      2     C
4   Green      2     D
5     Red      3     D
6     Red      3     A
7     Red      3     B
8   Green      4     C
9   Green      4     D
10  Green      4     E
11  Green      4     E
12    Red      5     B
13    Red      5     B
14    Red      5     D
15  Green      6     D
```

intended output:

```
     Item  Value Group
0     Red      1     A
4   Green      2     D
5     Red      3     D
6     Red      3     A
9   Green      4     D
10  Green      4     E
11  Green      4     E
12    Red      5     B
13    Red      5     B
14    Red      5     D
15  Green      6     D
```

current output:

```
     Item  Value Group
0     Red      1     A
1     Red      1     B
2     Red      1     B
4   Green      2     D
5     Red      3     D
6     Red      3     A
7     Red      3     B
11  Green      4     E
12    Red      5     B
13    Red      5     B
14    Red      5     D
15  Green      6     D
```

Comment: What's the problem here? @Chopin

Comment: There seems to be no way in which I can interpret the rules you provide that fit with your expected output. I get why rows 1 and 2 are removed (duplicates before row 3), row 3 (group C with first value 2), and row 8 (group C with first value 4). **Why is row 7 removed?** Also you use `Green` in your attempt at the solution which is very confusing to me as the colour doesn’t appear in your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Another possible way:

```
out=df.shift(-1)
#shifting the dataframe
cond=df['Value'].ne(out['Value']) & out['Group'].eq('C') 
#your initial condition
df=df[~cond].drop(df[cond].index+1)
#filtering out data
```

output of `df`:

```
    Item    Value   Group
0   Red     1   A
3   Green   2   D
4   Red     3   E
5   Red     3   A
6   Red     3   B
7   Green   4   B
8   Green   4   D
9   Green   4   E
10  Green   4   A
11  Red     5   B
12  Red     5   C
13  Red     5   D
14  Green   6   E
```

**Update:**

IIUC:

Try:

create a custom function which will calculate your conditions and give the index of rows where the condition match

```
def getindicies():
    out=df.shift(-1)
    cond=df['Value'].ne(out['Value']) & out['Group'].eq('C') 
    idx=df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x:x.duplicated(keep=False).any()).index
    to_drop=df.loc[:(df[cond].index+1)[-1]]
    return to_drop[to_drop.index.isin(idx)].index.tolist()+(df[cond].index+1).tolist()

#Finally call the function and remove those values:
df=df.drop(getindicies())
```

If you print `df` you will get your desired output

**OR**

let's extend the logic of [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68252282/14289892):

```
cond = df.Value.diff().ne(0) & df.Group.eq("C")
duplicates=df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x:x.duplicated(keep=False).any()).all(1)
to_drop = (cond | cond.shift(-1)) | duplicates
df=df[~to_drop].loc[:df[cond].index[-1]].append(df.loc[df[cond].index[-1]+1:])
#OR
df=pd.concat([df[~to_drop].loc[:df[cond].index[-1]],df.loc[df[cond].index[-1]+1:]])
```

If you print `df` you will get your desired output

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to drop all previous rows that are duplicates? Rather than previous row only?

Comment: @Chopin updated answer...kindlly have a look

Comment: Thanks @Anurag. I've updated your output in the question. Looks like more rows are being removed. I only need the previous duplicates rows between `Item`  `Value` `Group` to be removed.

Comment: @Chopin If I understand correctly then...updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Thanks. It's removing index `1-3` correctly but it's only removing index `8` and leaving `7`

Comment: @Chopin why 7 is removed?...if consider the logic of removing duplicates then isn't it index `[1,2,4,6,7,3,8]`  are going to removed in which `[1, 2, 4, 6, 7]` are the indices where values are duplicates and `[3,8]` are indicies where your condition matches?

Comment: Because I want to remove the previous duplicate rows. So `3` and `8` are indices that match conditions. So remove them, plus remove all previous duplicate rows, which are indices `1,2` and `7`.

Comment: @Chopin If I understand correctly then `6` is also duplicate isn't it? so `[3,8]` removed because they are satisfying your condition and `[1,2,6,7]` are duplicates so they are also removed

Comment: No, because index 6 is `Red,3,A`, while 7 is `Red,3,B`. So `Group` isn't duplicated. But when referring to index 3, the two previous rows are `Red,1,B` so they should be removed. This holds until they aren't duplicated, which is index 1 `Red,1,A`

Comment: @Chopin added another possible way...kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 3):

```
# form the condition
cond = df.Value.diff().ne(0) & df.Group.eq("C")

# also consider the previous row
to_drop = cond | cond.shift(-1)

# index with inverse of the mask
new_df = df[~to_drop]
```

Locations where `Value` is not equal to the previous one can be found via looking at the difference not being 0:

```
df.Value.diff().ne(0)
```

and `Group` being `"C"` is found with

```
df.Group.eq("C")
```

Combining them with "and":

```
cond = df.Value.diff().ne(0) & df.Group.eq("C")
```

Since you want to drop the previous row too, we can "or" with the shifted version of this:

```
to_drop = cond | cond.shift(-1)
```

which gives

```
>>> to_drop

0     False
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
```

Therefore final operation is indexing with inverse of this:

```
>>> new_df = df[~to_drop]
>>> new_df

     Item  Value Group
0     Red      1     A
3   Green      2     D
4     Red      3     E
5     Red      3     A
6     Red      3     B
7   Green      4     B
8   Green      4     D
9   Green      4     E
10  Green      4     A
11    Red      5     B
12    Red      5     C
13    Red      5     D
14  Green      6     E
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to drop all previous rows that are duplicates? Rather than previous row only?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: So row 2 and 3, both contain `Red` and `B`. I want to drop both of these duplicate rows plus `Green` and `C`. I'm only dropping one row previously. Not all previous duplicate rows.

Comment: I see, that's somewhat a different question and I don't know if this solution can be extended for it. Sorry maybe others can help.

Answer (score 1):

another way.

```
m=df['Value'].duplicated(keep='last')&df['Group'].ne('C')
n=(df['Group'].ne('C')&df['Group'].shift(-1).eq('C'))|(df['Group'].eq('C'))
df[~(m&n)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to drop all previous rows that are duplicates? Rather than previous row only?

Comment: What do you mean. Please expound

Comment: So row 2 and 3, both contain `Red` and `B`. I want to drop both of these duplicate rows plus `Green` and `C`. I'm only dropping the previous row only. Not all previous duplicate rows.

Comment: Your data and output mismatch. For instance row 13. Can you please correct the sample data and clearly state what the output should be